# How to see source code of RouteValueDictionary class

Tags: c#, reflector

I want see the source code of System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary class.
But Reflector can't disassemble it correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: I've managed to disassemble it fine with Reflector. What was wrong with it?

Comment: I don't know.
All class In assembly System.Web.Routing.dll can't be disassemble correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pastebin link for the code I just disassembled: http://pastebin.com/c1gQpBMG

Answer (score 1):

Using the new [.NET Reference Library (https://ReferenceSource.Microsoft.com/)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com), you can now see the exact source with comments. Here's the link to the [RouteValueDictionary source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=RouteValueDictionary).

Answer (score 0):

You opened the "Reference Assembles" version, which is a metadata-only version of the assembly used by Visual Studio for performance and multitargeting support.  You need to open assemblies under windows\microsoft.net\framework... in order to disassemble them.